VS Code failing to connect via remote SSH
I am trying to connect from my laptop to my desktop. Both are x86 machines running Linux.
[19:17:35.044] Log Level: 2
[19:17:35.063] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+desktop.home.lan", attempt 1
[19:17:35.064] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true
[19:17:35.064] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": true
[19:17:35.064] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[19:17:35.064] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[19:17:35.064] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[19:17:35.064] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[19:17:35.065] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[19:17:35.065] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[19:17:35.065] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[19:17:35.065] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[19:17:35.065] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[19:17:35.065] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[19:17:35.065] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[19:17:35.065] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[19:17:35.065] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[19:17:35.065] "remote.SSH.permitPtyAllocation": false
[19:17:35.066] "remote.SSH.preferredLocalPortRange: undefined
[19:17:35.066] "remote.SSH.useCurlAndWgetConfigurationFiles: false
[19:17:35.073] VS Code version: 1.95.3
[19:17:35.073] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.115.1
[19:17:35.073] linux x64
[19:17:35.079] SSH Resolver called for host: desktop.home.lan
[19:17:35.079] Setting up SSH remote "desktop.home.lan"
[19:17:35.088] Acquiring local install lock: /tmp/vscode-remote-ssh-0d16f0fc-install.lock
[19:17:35.090] Looking for existing server data file at /home/user@home.lan/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-0d16f0fc-f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813-0.115.1-es/data.json
[19:17:35.091] No existing data file
[19:17:35.092] Using commit id "f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813" and quality "stable" for server
[19:17:35.097] Script variables:
 {
  "InstallExitCode.24": "AlreadyInProgress",
  "InstallExitCode.25": "ServerDownloadFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.26": "NoDownloaderAvailable",
  "InstallExitCode.27": "UnsupportedArch",
  "InstallExitCode.28": "StatusCheckFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.29": "NeedInsidersArch",
  "InstallExitCode.30": "NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck",
  "InstallExitCode.31": "ServerTransferFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.32": "ServerFailedToStart",
  "InstallExitCode.33": "NeedInsidersWindows",
  "InstallExitCode.34": "CreateInstallDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.35": "UnsupportedPlatform",
  "InstallExitCode.36": "ServerTerminatedCVE20201416",
  "InstallExitCode.37": "UnpackFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.38": "ChangeDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.AlreadyInProgress": "24",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerDownloadFailed": "25",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailable": "26",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck": "30",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedArch": "27",
  "InstallExitCode.StatusCheckFailed": "28",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersArch": "29",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTransferFailed": "31",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerFailedToStart": "32",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersWindows": "33",
  "InstallExitCode.CreateInstallDirFailed": "34",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedPlatform": "35",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTerminatedCVE20201416": "36",
  "InstallExitCode.UnpackFailed": "37",
  "InstallExitCode.ChangeDirFailed": "38",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Success": "success",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Error": "error",
  "InstallUnpackCode.MissingFiles": "missingFiles",
  "uuid": "44aeae6a1535",
  "startMarker": "44aeae6a1535: running",
  "commitId": "f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813",
  "quality": "stable",
  "token": "111111a1-111a-111a-1aa1-a1a111a11aa1",
  "vscodeAgentFolder": "$HOME/.vscode-server",
  "allowClientDownload": "1",
  "forceClientDownload": "0",
  "cliNameInArchive": "code",
  "ignoreWgetConfigFlag": " --no-config ",
  "ignoreCurlConfigFlag": " --disable ",
  "wgetTriesSegment": "--tries=1",
  "listenArgs": "--on-host=127.0.0.1 --on-port",
  "getDownloadServerStartTrigger": "44aeae6a1535:trigger_server_download",
  "getDownloadServerEndTrigger": "44aeae6a1535:trigger_server_download_end",
  "getProgressDownloading": "44aeae6a1535%%1%%",
  "getProgressInstalling": "44aeae6a1535%%2%%"
}
[19:17:35.101] Install and start server if needed
[19:17:35.107] PATH: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/user@home.lan/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
[19:17:35.107] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[19:17:35.123] > OpenSSH_9.8p1, OpenSSL 3.2.2 4 Jun 2024

[19:17:35.135] askpass server listening on /run/user/1400601103/vscode-ssh-askpass-cbc4fd4cf1bc45c46fcd25e07741749e2f745409.sock
[19:17:35.135] Spawning local server with {"serverId":1,"ipcHandlePath":"/run/user/1400601103/vscode-ssh-askpass-095d8dada2ef92065b0b50c89b4fe788ac731057.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","42769","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","desktop.home.lan"],"serverDataFolderName":".vscode-server","dataFilePath":"/home/user@home.lan/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-0d16f0fc-f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813-0.115.1-es/data.json"}
[19:17:35.136] Local server env: {"SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/run/user/1400601103/keyring/ssh","SHELL":"/bin/fish","DISPLAY":":0","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/var/home/user@home.lan/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/usr/share/code/code","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS":"","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/var/home/user@home.lan/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/run/user/1400601103/vscode-ssh-askpass-cbc4fd4cf1bc45c46fcd25e07741749e2f745409.sock"}
[19:17:35.145] Spawned 918426
[19:17:35.146] Using connect timeout of 17 seconds
[19:17:35.266] > local-server-1> Running ssh connection command: ssh -v -T -D 42769 -o ConnectTimeout=15 desktop.home.lan
[19:17:35.271] > local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=918434
[19:17:35.277] stderr> OpenSSH_9.8p1, OpenSSL 3.2.2 4 Jun 2024
[19:17:35.394] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:Df/6fMjI1htQNEILiBNM4l64pd2BQbuHRUXSUwY/vG8
[19:17:35.577] stderr> Authenticated to desktop.home.lan ([192.168.43.101]:22) using "gssapi-with-mic".

It seems to me that everything worked and I it has successfully logged in. However at this point nothing happens: it waits doing nothing until the timeout expires and then:
[19:17:52.150] Terminating local server
[19:17:52.155] Resolver error: Error: Connecting with SSH timed out
    at v.Timeout (/var/home/user@home.lan/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1/out/extension.js:2:493557)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/home/user@home.lan/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1/out/extension.js:2:552428)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:581:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7)
[19:17:52.165] ------


[19:17:52.171] Local server exit: 15
[19:17:52.721] Opening exec server for ssh-remote+desktop.home.lan
[19:17:52.759] Acquiring local install lock: /tmp/vscode-remote-ssh-0d16f0fc-install.lock
[19:17:52.759] Initizing new exec server for ssh-remote+desktop.home.lan
[19:17:52.762] Looking for existing server data file at /home/user@home.lan/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-0d16f0fc-f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813-0.115.1-es/data.json
[19:17:52.762] No existing data file
[19:17:52.763] Using commit id "f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813" and quality "stable" for server
[19:17:52.767] Script variables:
 {
  "InstallExitCode.24": "AlreadyInProgress",
  "InstallExitCode.25": "ServerDownloadFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.26": "NoDownloaderAvailable",
  "InstallExitCode.27": "UnsupportedArch",
  "InstallExitCode.28": "StatusCheckFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.29": "NeedInsidersArch",
  "InstallExitCode.30": "NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck",
  "InstallExitCode.31": "ServerTransferFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.32": "ServerFailedToStart",
  "InstallExitCode.33": "NeedInsidersWindows",
  "InstallExitCode.34": "CreateInstallDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.35": "UnsupportedPlatform",
  "InstallExitCode.36": "ServerTerminatedCVE20201416",
  "InstallExitCode.37": "UnpackFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.38": "ChangeDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.AlreadyInProgress": "24",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerDownloadFailed": "25",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailable": "26",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck": "30",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedArch": "27",
  "InstallExitCode.StatusCheckFailed": "28",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersArch": "29",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTransferFailed": "31",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerFailedToStart": "32",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersWindows": "33",
  "InstallExitCode.CreateInstallDirFailed": "34",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedPlatform": "35",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTerminatedCVE20201416": "36",
  "InstallExitCode.UnpackFailed": "37",
  "InstallExitCode.ChangeDirFailed": "38",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Success": "success",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Error": "error",
  "InstallUnpackCode.MissingFiles": "missingFiles",
  "uuid": "69b41b3e99ad",
  "startMarker": "69b41b3e99ad: running",
  "commitId": "f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813",
  "quality": "stable",
  "token": "1a1aa11a-1aa1-1111-1111-a1111a111aaa",
  "vscodeAgentFolder": "$HOME/.vscode-server",
  "allowClientDownload": "1",
  "forceClientDownload": "0",
  "cliNameInArchive": "code",
  "ignoreWgetConfigFlag": " --no-config ",
  "ignoreCurlConfigFlag": " --disable ",
  "wgetTriesSegment": "--tries=1",
  "listenArgs": "--on-host=127.0.0.1 --on-port",
  "getDownloadServerStartTrigger": "69b41b3e99ad:trigger_server_download",
  "getDownloadServerEndTrigger": "69b41b3e99ad:trigger_server_download_end",
  "getProgressDownloading": "69b41b3e99ad%%1%%",
  "getProgressInstalling": "69b41b3e99ad%%2%%"
}
[19:17:52.768] Install and start server if needed
[19:17:52.776] askpass server listening on /run/user/1400601103/vscode-ssh-askpass-f5a08f7dd358e3c0cdf5482f9ef31b116d663d07.sock
[19:17:52.776] Spawning local server with {"serverId":2,"ipcHandlePath":"/run/user/1400601103/vscode-ssh-askpass-ebe4c6f359e87b561a50aadf0d663b2d21bcfdff.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","42769","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","desktop.home.lan"],"serverDataFolderName":".vscode-server","dataFilePath":"/home/user@home.lan/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-0d16f0fc-f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813-0.115.1-es/data.json"}
[19:17:52.776] Local server env: {"SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/run/user/1400601103/keyring/ssh","SHELL":"/bin/fish","DISPLAY":":0","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/var/home/user@home.lan/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/usr/share/code/code","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS":"","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/var/home/user@home.lan/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/run/user/1400601103/vscode-ssh-askpass-f5a08f7dd358e3c0cdf5482f9ef31b116d663d07.sock"}
[19:17:52.785] Spawned 919133
[19:17:52.786] Using connect timeout of 17 seconds
[19:17:52.911] > local-server-2> Running ssh connection command: ssh -v -T -D 42769 -o ConnectTimeout=15 desktop.home.lan
[19:17:52.920] > local-server-2> Spawned ssh, pid=919142
[19:17:52.930] stderr> OpenSSH_9.8p1, OpenSSL 3.2.2 4 Jun 2024
[19:17:53.003] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:Df/6fMjI1htQNEILiBNM4l64pd2BQbuHRUXSUwY/vG8
[19:17:53.160] stderr> Authenticated to desktop.home.lan ([192.168.43.101]:22) using "gssapi-with-mic".
[19:18:09.787] Terminating local server
[19:18:09.788] Exec server for ssh-remote+desktop.home.lan failed: Error: Connecting with SSH timed out
[19:18:09.788] Error opening exec server for ssh-remote+desktop.home.lan: Error: Connecting with SSH timed out
[19:18:09.810] Local server exit: 15

I am not clear what the problem is. The only thing special is that because the two machines use sssd they authenticate from a Samba AD that I run, which allows for passwordless login (I do not need to supply a password, Kerberos takes care of authentication). So access is passwordless, but from the log (before the pause) it seems to be trying to ask for a password despite the fact that one is not needed:
...
[19:17:35.135] askpass server listening on /run/user/1400601103/vscode-ssh-askpass-cbc4fd4cf1bc45c46fcd25e07741749e2f745409.sock
...
[19:17:35.577] stderr> Authenticated to desktop.home.lan ([192.168.43.101]:22) using "gssapi-with-mic".
...

Is VS Code not smart enough to understand that no password is needed? Do I have to configure something somewhere?
NOTE: if I use a local account on the target machine that is different from my AD account (e.g. localuser instead of user@home.lan) then I am prompted for a password and the whole thing works. This is why I am suspecting it has something to do with passwordless login...
EDIT: This is not related to password-less authentication. I edited my config to add `GSSAPIAuthentication no" which prevents Kerberos from performing the authentication so I am now prompted for a password (just like when using a local user account). After entering the password, I get the same timeout. The error is

Failed to parse remote port from server output

as shown here:
[19:56:11.296] Got password response
[19:56:11.297] Interactor gave response: ********
[19:56:11.298] Cleaning up other-window auth server
[19:56:11.301] Using connect timeout of 17 seconds
[19:56:11.321] stderr> Connection closed by 192.168.43.101 port 22
[19:56:11.323] > local-server-1> ssh child died, shutting down
[19:56:11.337] Local server exit: 0
[19:56:11.338] Received install output: local-server-1> Running ssh connection command: ssh -v -T -D 36817 -o ConnectTimeout=15 desktop.home.lan
local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=997575
OpenSSH_9.8p1, OpenSSL 3.2.2 4 Jun 2024
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:Df/6fMjI1htQNEILiBNM4l64pd2BQbuHRUXSUwY/vG8
Connection closed by 192.168.43.101 port 22
local-server-1> ssh child died, shutting down

[19:56:11.339] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[19:56:11.343] Resolver error: Error: 
    at v.Create (/var/home/user@home.lan/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1/out/extension.js:2:493431)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (/var/home/user@home.lan/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1/out/extension.js:2:490753)
    at e (/var/home/user@home.lan/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1/out/extension.js:2:545236)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /var/home/user@home.lan/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1/out/extension.js:2:567561
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (/var/home/user@home.lan/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1/out/extension.js:2:571256)
    at async /var/home/user@home.lan/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1/out/extension.js:2:541941
    at async T (/var/home/user@home.lan/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1/out/extension.js:2:539992)
    at async t.resolveWithLocalServer (/var/home/user@home.lan/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1/out/extension.js:2:541481)
    at async P (/var/home/user@home.lan/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1/out/extension.js:2:564693)
    at async t.resolve (/var/home/user@home.lan/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1/out/extension.js:2:568667)
    at async /var/home/user@home.lan/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1/out/extension.js:2:839059
[19:56:11.358] ------


Seems like this is due to me using fish as my shell. I changed my shell to bash and now this works...
